# Using Postgres to take one object from each group

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am working with a table of cats and am trying to write a statement that will select one cat from each age group.

this is my table

```
pets=# SELECT * FROM cats;
 id |   name   | gender | age |     intake_date     |    adoption_date    
----+----------+--------+-----+---------------------+---------------------
  1 | Mushi    | M      |   1 | 2016-01-09 00:00:00 | 2016-03-22 00:00:00
  2 | Seashell | F      |   7 | 2016-01-09 00:00:00 | 
  3 | Azul     | M      |   3 | 2016-01-11 00:00:00 | 2016-04-17 00:00:00
  4 | Victoire | M      |   7 | 2016-01-11 00:00:00 | 2016-09-01 00:00:00
  5 | Nala     | F      |   1 | 2016-01-12 00:00:00 | 
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: Postgres 9.1 is no longer supported or maintained. You should plan an upgrade to a current version now: https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Answer (score 2):

Use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (c.age) c.*
from cats c
order by age;
```